# Is it possible to stringify enum values in C++11 without macros?

Tags: c++, c++11

I know that it's possible to write a "register" macro that will map their values to their string representations. Is there however some new magic in C++11 that makes it possible to do without macros and any registration boilerplate?

To make it clear, I would like to be able to print the identifiers of enum variables, such as:

```
enum Days { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday };
auto d = Days::Sunday;
std::cout << magic << d;
```

Should output

```
Days::Sunday
```

Comment: No: tokens in C++ source code have no runtime significance (except literal-value tokens, of course).

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the motivation? Debugging print-s?

Comment: just create `std::string day_names[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not really possible. You need macros (preferably) or to extend the compiler for additional tricks (you might extend GCC with plugins or with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) to provide a special `_my_enum_name_builtin` function, but I don't think it is a good idea). You could also (assuming the executable is built with debugging information kept) extract the name from debugging information.

If you really need that, a perhaps simpler way is to generate some (C++) code, which is nearly what macros are doing for you. The [Qt Moc](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/moc.html) could be an inspiration for you.

Comment: I don't think I could do that without parsing the C++ sources first which I'll never do unless someone points a gun at me and says to do it. :) but thanks :)

Comment: If the code base is large enough (e.g. several hundred thousands lines of source code), you might consider extending GCC (e.g. with MELT) to suit your needs. And extending GCC gives you the power of GCC (in particular its parsing &optimizing abilities). But that will take some time.

Comment: It's not that big, and I was just wondering if it's possible to do in a convenient way... before extending GCC I think I'd try GCC-XML which outputs these kinds of information.

Comment: GCC XML is not really maintained any more.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Seemed like a handy tool in such situations.

Comment: You can also use the Clang libraries to parse C++. It's maintained and supposed to be pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

No. Not possible without macros.

Answer (score 0):

As already told is not possible. But you can consider using a class as enum.

```
class Day
{
   enum _Day{ Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wensday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday }

public:
    static Day Sun;
    static Day Mon;
    static Day Tue;
    static Day Wen;
    static Day Thu;
    static Day Fri;
    static Day Sat;

    operator    int() const     { return _day; }

    int         toInt() const   { return _day; }
    std::string toStr() const   { return _name;}

private:
    Day(_Day day, std::string name) 
        : _day(day), _name(std::move(name))
    {
    }

  _Day _day;
  std::string _name;
};

Day Day::Mon = Day(_Day::Sun, "Sunday");
Day Day::Mon = Day(_Day::Mon, "Monday");

// ....
```

Stronger typing, works exactly like an enum, with the additional features you need.

Moreover you could add all the convenience functionality you could desire, for instance:

```
operator std::string() const;
bool operator==(const Day&);
Day& operator=(const Day&);
```